# Gson Malformed Exception via parse

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gson

Hello my service is going to be parse Json. But I am having Malformed exception.
My Code Below;

```
 Object listOfGroups = sthService.getSthList();
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    
    JsonArray jsonArray = gson.fromJson(listOfGroups.toString(), JsonObject.class)
         .getAsJsonArray("memberNameList");
    
    List<String> myId = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>()) {
    }.getType();
    
      for(JsonElement element : JsonArray) {
    
        Json jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
    
        String sthIndicator = jsonObject.get("readInd").getAsString();
    
        if (sthIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    
         String itemId = jsonObject.get("itemId").getAsString();
         myId.add(itemId);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does `listOfGroups.toString()` return?

Comment: returns an object value

Comment: Can you add that value to your question? Gson fails to parse your "object value". Hence we need to examine it to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Alexy thank you for your answer but its just object value, nothing else.

Comment: can you post the full exception, so we at least know which line is failing...

Answer (score 0):

Gson gives you this exception if it unable to map the received JSON string with your JsonObject.class probably because of datatype mismatch.

Either verify the datatypes for each attribute or
Use ObjectMapper rather than using Gson.
ObjectMapper handles the Json String irrespective of your datatype

Comment: How to convert ObjectMapper

Comment: Go through this -> https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial